# Node.js Date Timezones and getMonth()

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I was just wondering why the following code results in the value of 7 (august) on my node.js box, but not on my browser.

```
new Date(1378008000 * 1000).getMonth()
```

Is it not assuming Unix Epoch GMT timezone?  What timezone would it be assuming and how should I be handling things like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Both node.js and my browser (firefox aurora) return the same value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMonth` returns the month in the local time zone, so it indeed depends on the settings in use.

If you want to have the month base on UTC time, use [`getUTCMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth) and the rest of the getUTC* family.